# Xcode8 linking doesn't read xcconfig variables correctly

Tags: xcode, linker

I refer a bash variable in a xcconfig file I created in Xcode8, Os X El Capitan, in the form:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $MY_LIB_PATH
```

`$MY_LIB_PATH` is set through a bash script. The thing works, because I set a `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` the same way and the compiler resolves it. This is a linker-related problem.

Xcodebuild (through gym) command line builds works correcty, and creates an ipa; while building in xcode yields the error:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L$MY_LIB_PATH'

If I drag'n'drop the library into Xcode, a new setting is written in the build settings and everything works fine. So it appears to be a bug in the way xcode calls the linker, or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: Try: $(MY_LIB_PATH)